# swift can't find textfield in scope even when its in the same viewController

Tags: swift

I need to print value of `txtField` after clicking the button, `txtField` is on the viewcotroller but xcode returns an error `cannot find 'txtField' in scope` but they are in the same view

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
        button.backgroundColor = .green
        button.setTitle("Test Button", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        var txtField: UITextField = UITextField()
        txtField.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 70, width: 200, height: 30)
        txtField.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        
        self.view.addSubview(txtField)
    }
    
    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        print(txtField.text)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, no, it's not in scope. Your `var txtField` is inside the `viewDidLoad` function. No other function's code can see inside this function, so the variable is not in scope from within another function such as your `buttonAction`.

In general the rule that things inside a scope can see only things that at a *higher* level of scope. If `var txtField` appeared *outside* both `viewDidLoad` and `buttonAction` (i.e. an instance property), then code inside both would be able to see it.

It's an easy move to make:

```
var txtField: UITextField = UITextField()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
    button.backgroundColor = .green
    button.setTitle("Test Button", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
    txtField.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 70, width: 200, height: 30)
    txtField.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    
    self.view.addSubview(txtField)
}

@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    print(txtField.text)
}
```

Comment: Understanding scope is extremely basic to even the most rudimentary knowledge of Swift. You might want to see my online book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch01.html#_scope_and_lifetime

Answer (score 0):

In your code `txtField` is declared  in `viewDidLoad` on line

```
var txtField: UITextField = UITextField()
```

Therefore out of the scope of buttonAction.

To mitigate this place

```
txtField
```

out of scope as a instance variable

Comment: you mean as an instance property of the UIViewController. global vars are not recommended

Comment: Yes sorry good catch

Answer (score 0):

The error is that are in 2 different function, override or @objc doesn't change this simple thing. So move the txtField initialization outside them so can be readed or written by both.

```
var txtField: UITextField = UITextField()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
        button.backgroundColor = .green
        button.setTitle("Test Button", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        
        txtField.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 70, width: 200, height: 30)
        txtField.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        
        self.view.addSubview(txtField)
    }
    
    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        print(txtField.text)
    }
```